# Is there a way to handle routes in electron?

Tags: node.js, electron

1) What to use for routing in `Electron` project?

2) Do I have to use front-end framework like `VueJS`?

3) Can I use [BlazeJS](http://blazejs.org) with `Electron`?

Answer (score 4):

1) Depends on the framework you use. You can use routing, and it will basically make the Electron app function as a SPA.

2) You don't have to use VueJS. You can use plain javascript, Angular, React, etc.

3) You can't yet use Blaze directly. It isn't in NPM yet, and is Meteor only based on their [documentation](https://github.com/meteor/blaze#quick-start). If you can figure out how to integrate Meteor into your Electron project, then most likely you can use Blaze through that.

**EDIT**

To answer the question in your comment:

You can take a look at the [browser history api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) for doing something like routing in plain javascript. Otherwise, check out [this blog](http://joakim.beng.se/blog/posts/a-javascript-router-in-20-lines.html) for ideas or [navigo](https://github.com/krasimir/navigo) for something you don't have to code from scratch

Comment: Can I implement dynamic routes using plain JavaScript?

Comment: I updated my answer to address this new question, but next time please ask a new question